# Determine p(z) by solving dp/dz = -(1/λ)(p)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Determine p(z) by solving the differential equation
dp/dz = -1/λ*p 
where λ is a constant, and find the particular solution that satisfies the
initial condition p(0) = P , where P is a constant.

I've assumed that using seperation of variables method is suitable as the RHS is a multiple of two functions, is this correct and if so have i approached it in the right way?

1/p dp = λ^1/p dz

Integrate both sides

ln|p|= 1/λ*ln|p|+C

Comment: Please use Latex/MathJax notation. Do you now which $f$ satisfies $f' = cf$?

Comment: It is hard to parse your expression.  Do you mean $-\frac 1{\lambda p}$ or $-\frac 1{\lambda}p$?

Comment: Sorry guys, struggled to figure out how to put the greek letter in. -(1/λ)(p)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $p$ is in the **numerator** on the RHS:
\begin{align}
\frac{dp}{dz} &= -\frac1\lambda p \\
\frac{dp}p&=-\frac{dz}\lambda \\
\ln p &=-\frac z\lambda + C \\
p(z) &= p(0)e^{-\frac z\lambda}
\end{align}

Assuming that $p$ is in the **denominator** on the RHS:
\begin{align}
\frac{dp}{dz} &= -\frac1{\lambda p} \\
pdp&=-\frac{dz}\lambda \\
\frac12 p^2 &=-\frac z\lambda + C \\
p(z) &= \sqrt{p(0)^2-\frac{2z}\lambda}
\end{align}